# anybody knows what this means? tatto from my brother

Tags: translation

[image]

anybody knows what this means? tatto from my brother

Comment: 塗 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1664/

Comment: Why don't you just ask your brother?

Comment: bkrs Forum "help decipher image" (Помогите распознать картинку) provides unconditional help with images

Answer (score 2):

This character is 塗, pronounced tú.

Dictionary definition is:

[v] paint; spread on. Ex: 塗抹

[v] scribble. Ex: 塗鴉

[v] erase. Ex: 塗改

[n] mud. Ex: 塗炭

[a] muddled, silly. Ex: 糊塗

There is a old saying in Chinese "難得糊塗" (literally: it's hard to be muddled), which is said by one famous scholar. It means that do not be too clever when dealing with stuff in the world. (Where ignorance is bliss, it's folly to be wise)